# How configure inline style and html template in `angular.json`?

Tags: angular-cli, angular-schematics

It look like all tutorials show how config it in the old `angular.cli.json` format.

```
"defaults": {
  "styleExt": "css",
  "component": {
    "inlineStyle":true,
    "inlineTemplate":true
  }
}
```

but not in the `angular.json` format. 
and that arises the error `Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used`

So how I can change the configuration of an existing project to generate component with an inline template and CSS/SCSS

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

After researching the `angular CLI` command and generate a new project with that setting I come with that solution :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineTemplate": true,
          "inlineStyle": true,
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      }, ....
}
```